# What type of trading is taxable in a TFSA investment acount?

Tags: investing, canada, tfsa, canada-revenue-agency

I always assumed that capital gains in TFSA is non-taxable until I read that people who use TFSA investment account for day trading are starting to being [audited by the CRA](https://business.financialpost.com/personal-finance/stop-using-your-tfsa-to-frequently-trade-stocks-the-cra-may-see-it-as-business-income).

So, what types of trading activity are taxable?

Not that I do day trading but I sold some ETF when the market was falling and a couple of weeks later bought them back when it stabilized.